# Query Opportunity Partner Name

Tags: soql

I am trying to write a SOQL query that pulls info from opportunities, and I need to pull out the name of the primary partner accout(if there is one). This isn't for a trigger, but for a nightly data export.

Here is the Query I have now:

```
SELECT 
    Id, Account.ps_company_id__C, Account.name,Owner.name,
    Opportunity_ID_18__c, Compensation_Treatment__c,
    Account_Market__c, Account.Region__c,Type, 
        (SELECT NAME, IsPrimary FROM OpportunityPartner WHERE IsPrimary = TRUE)
```

Someone mentioned that I should change it to this, but the field didn't pull when I tried to run this SOQL query export with data loader.

```
 (SELECT AccountTo.Name, IsPrimary FROM OpportunityPartnersFrom WHERE
  IsPrimary = True ) FROM Opportunity
```

This was the full query, I omitted the FROM Opportunity clause.

```
SELECT

     id,Account.ps_company_id__C,Account.name,Owner.name,PFIN_Intgr_Contract_Num__c,Opp‌​ortunity_ID_18__c,
     Compensation_Treatment__c,Account_Market__c, Account.Region__c,Type,Platform__c,CloseDate,
     StageName,Multi_Year_Deal__c,Amount,Ye‌​ar_2_Amount__c,Year_3_Amount__c,Year_4_Amount__c,Year_5_Amount__c, 
     (Select AccountTo.Name, IsPrimary from OpportunityPartnersFrom where IsPrimary = True ) 
     FROM Opportunity
```

Can anyone guide me an appropriate way ? Thanks in advanced for your help!

Comment: The relationship is probably `OpportunityPartners` if I had to guess, but I don't have a reference on hand to double check.

Comment: Refering to your second child clause. I don't understand why you included two.

Comment: And your first clause has no `FROM` clause...

Comment: This was the full query, I omitted the FROM Opportunity clause.          SELECT  id,Account.ps_company_id__C,Account.name,Owner.name,PFIN_Intgr_Contract_Num__c,Opportunity_ID_18__c,Compensation_Treatment__c,Account_Market__c,
Account.Region__c,Type,Platform__c,CloseDate,StageName,Multi_Year_Deal__c,Amount,Year_2_Amount__c,Year_3_Amount__c,Year_4_Amount__c,Year_5_Amount__c, (Select AccountTo.Name, IsPrimary from OpportunityPartnersFrom where IsPrimary = True ) FROM Opportunity

Comment: You can't put a WHERE clause inside a subquery, that would need to be the WHERE clause for Opportunity. WHERE OpportunityPartner.isPrimary = true

Comment: Would also assume this is a typo `from OpportunityPartnersFrom` and should be `from OpportunityPartners`.

Comment: @crmprogdev You can put WHERE clauses in a subquery, I do it all the time.  Also the OpportunityPartnersFrom is the correct relationship name.

OP I don't see any errors in your SOQL query.  Is it possible that there is no data, or that you don't have access rights?

Comment: @DougB. My bad. Every time I've tried using a WHERE clause inside a subquery, I've always received error messages. Will have to read more in the SOQL reference on this. I didn't look at the object reference before commenting on the object as I usually do, again, my bad. Thanks for the corrections.